# What is wrong with this foreach loop?

Tags: php, html, loops, foreach

I am trying to allow my users to update quantities in the database, by providing them some input fields, I know that the sql update query is perfect, because if i DONT use the foreach loop, it will submit and update the last textfield only.

But I need the foreach loop so it will loop through all the textfields and update them all in the database. Can somebody please help me figure out why it's not updating with this foreach loop? Lots of thanks in advance :)

```
foreach($_POST['items'] as $p=>$q) 
{
   // working sql code is in here.
}
```

And the fields are dynamically generated like so:

```
  $ct->data[$key][0]='<input type="text" value="'.$ct->data[$key][0].'" name="product" />';
  $ct->data[$key][1]='<input type="text" value='.$ct->data[$key][1].' id="qty" name="items[' . $ct->data[$key][1] . ']" />';
  $ct->data[$key][2]='<input type="submit" value="Update Item">';
  $ct->data[$key][3]='<p name="price">'.$ct->data[$key][3].'</p>';
```

Answer (score 2):

You should ALWAYS check if a variable exists. That's no more that normal and should have been lession 1.
You can't iterate over `$_POST['items']` if `$_POST['items']` doesn't exist (obviously). So you have to check if the form has been submitted.

One way is:

```
if ( isset($_POST['items']) ) {
  // foreach ( $_POST['items'] ....
}
```

I always like to be on the safe side and check for type as well:

```
if ( isset($_POST['items']) ) {
  // form submitted at least
  if ( is_array($_POST['items']) ) {
    // and it's an array as it should be
    foreach ( ....
  }
}
```

POST variables are never set in a GET request, so doing the foreach first time on a page is useless. That's what the check is for: 'is the form submitted and do the necessary post vars exist?'

Comment: The form WAS being submitted before i added the foreach loop when I was just submitting one thing, but I can't do that, i need ALL quantities submitted, however, I just changed it to POST (as I had it about half hour ago) and it does not submit anything with POST. Using GET submits it just fine, as it was before i added the foreach loop.

Comment: Maybe it was submitted, but obviously you're not checking for it, since I see the error on /checkout.php -> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in E:\web\[site]\checkout.php on line 96

Comment: You only get that error when you haven't added anything to the cart.

Comment: And I did check for it when you posted your answer, but removed the check as it didn't return anything at all

Comment: You should add the check nontheless. Always add the check. And other checks. Don't you ever trust 'the user'. The user sends whatever he wants, not what you want. So make sure you receive what you expect.

Comment: Details. (Didn't mean to post just yet.) Add this the line before your foreach: `var_dump($_POST['items'])`. It'll probably say NULL.

Comment: Also, you're going to break your form if any of those data fields contain quotes. `<input ... value='This is O'Brien's Beer' ..>` is not going to render how you think.

Answer (score 0):

The name of the `items` input field should just be `items[]`.

So:

```
# Good 
$ct->data[$key][1]='<input type="text" value='.$ct->data[$key][1].' id="qty" name="items[]" />';


# Bad 
$ct->data[$key][1]='<input type="text" value='.$ct->data[$key][1].' id="qty" name="items[' . $ct->data[$key][1] . ']" />';
```

Comment: Thank you, but that good example you provided hasn't had any effect whatsoever

Comment: Also it's not a good example and just plain wrong. If you get the data from somewhere you might like to keep the same keys, so you WILL name the elements like `items[3]` instead of the keyless and surprising `items[]`

Comment: Yup, your edited version is exactly what I changed it to, and had no effect at all

Answer (score 0):

What values are you seeing?

```
foreach($_POST['items'] as $p=>$q) {
   print "$p: $q\n";
}
```

Comment: I know. I'm asking you to print the values to debug it. And "lol" doesn't qualify as punctuation.